# How to create 2 except blocks to raise different kinds of errors?

Tags: python

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
try:
    user_index_num = int(input(' Enter a number here: '))
    value = int(input(' Enter an element here: '))
except Exception:
    raise
except IndexError:
    raise
if not 0 <= user_index_num <= len(myList)-1:
    raise IndexError(f'Index {user_index_num} list assignment index out of range')

myList.insert(user_index_num, value)
print(myList)
```

Need to fulfill the following requirements but can't seem the quite get there.

If the input of the program is

```
15
3
```

The output of the program is

```
Index 15 Error list assignment index out of range
```

Example:
If the input of the program is

```
3
T
```

The output of the program is

```
Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You are probably having issues because `except Exception` is above `except IndexError` meaning that the second except block will never execute.

Comment: `except Exception` catches everything.

Comment: So I'm asking how to get both except to run when they are called I suppose.....when letters are given the except block works as planned however when input 1 is larger than input 2 it doesn't execute the pre configured except block

Comment: Does it *really* need to be in 1 `try-except-except` block? A common practice is to split the error-checks/validations and try-except's into multiple blocks.

Comment: These are my instructions so I would assume it has to be one?    Use a try block to perform all the statements. Use an except block to catch any IndexError and output an exception message. Use another except block to catch any ValueError caused by invalid input and to output an exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
index = -1
try:
    index = int(input(' Enter an index here: '))
    value = int(input(' Enter a value here: '))
    if 0 < index < len(myList):
        myList.insert(index, value)
    else:
        raise IndexError
except ValueError:
    print('You need to enter valid numbers!')
except IndexError:
    print(f'Index {index} out of range for list of values')

print(myList)
```

This raises an `IndexError` if an index is provided that's outside the existing range for `myList` (otherwise, the `.insert()` would just snap to the closest value).

It also catches both types of exceptions, because there is no broader exception being caught before the relevant exception (as in your example, where `except Exception` would prevent other exceptions from being caught after it).

If your point is that you don't want to explicitly specify `ValueError`, but rather want to catch all of them, something like this works:

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
index = -1
try:
    index = int(input(' Enter an index here: '))
    value = int(input(' Enter a value here: '))
    if 0 < index < len(myList):
        myList.insert(index, value)
    else:
        raise IndexError
except IndexError:
    print(f'Index {index} out of range for list of values')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(myList)
```

Execution still continues, as the generic exception is caught as `e` and displayed, without an uncaught exception ending the program. Note how the generic `Exception` is caught *after* the more specific `IndexError`.

Finally, note that `index` is set to a value to avoid a situation where `int()` or  `input()` were to somehow raise an `IndexError`, in which case `index` would not have a value when printed, raising another exception, which would again terminate your program. This seems silly: after all, when would `int()` or `input()` ever raise an `IndexError`? But Python has no straightforward way of knowing what exceptions might be raised and thus your IDE will likely give you a warning if you don't set `index` to some value like -1 beforehand.

(Edit: changed the default for `index` to -1, to have a value that's actually invalid and could be checked for in the exception handling code)

You mentioned you need to stop execution after an error was caught. There's two good ways to go about that. If you catch the error and just want a friendly message for the user before terminating, you should end the program with `exit(1)` (or some other non-zero number, so that whoever started your program can know something didn't end well - you can use different codes to indicate different problems).

```
except ValueError:
    print('You need to enter valid numbers!')
    exit(1)
```

Or, perhaps your code is called from some other code and after catching the error yourself and printing a message, you want that code to be able to catch it again:

```
except ValueError:
    print('You need to enter valid numbers!')
    raise
```

This re-raises the error as caught. Generally, it's bad practice to just allow uncaught exceptions to end your program - the whole point of an exception is that it should be, well ... an exception.

Comment: So first of all Thank you very much you got me farther than I have by myself. With that said the program execution should end after an error is raised, I understand why one would want to have the program continue but for the assignment it should end.

Comment: You can always print a nice error message after catching the exception and then `exit(1)` (the 1 lets the OS know something went wrong, which is helpful), or if you want to catch the exception somewhere outside your own code, you can re-raise the exception with `raise`

Answer (score 0):

I slightly edited your suggestion as follows.

```
 myList = [1, 2, 3, 4] index = -1 try:
     index = int(input())
     value = int(input())
     if 0 < index < len(myList):
         myList.insert(index, value)
         print(myList)
     else:
         raise IndexError except IndexError:
     print(f'Index {index} Error list assignment index out of range') except Exception as e:
     print('Input Exception:', e)
```

I'm pretty sure this is what my instructor is looking for....

one down only 20 more to go lol...thanks for the help